# r mlogit error: system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mlogit

I am using library(mlogit) in R and I am stuck at the error message saying:

```
Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 8.41187e-25
```

Using mlogit.data function I have made following structure.

```
x <- mlogit.data(choice = "choice", shape = "long", data, alt.var = "alt", chid.var = "chid", varying = 7:11)

> head(x, n=9)
    chid choice    x1  x2     x3     x4      y1       y2   y3     y4    y5 alt   
1.1    1  FALSE     1   1      4      7 0.04407  2490.17    0  80.00 2.277   1    
1.2    1  FALSE     1   1      4      7 0.06035  3300.83    0 239.00 2.421   2
1.3    1  FALSE     1   1      4      7 0.06757  4450.70    0 242.37 2.555   3    
1.4    1   TRUE     1   1      4      7 0.08850  5840.50    0 423.79 2.712   4
1.5    1  FALSE     1   1      4      7 0.11074 13240.38    0 618.03 2.858   5
1.6    1  FALSE     1   1      4      7 0.11990 15630.13    0 921.17 2.972   6
1.7    1  FALSE     1   1      4      7 0.04715  7800.00    0 320.00 2.463   7
1.8    1  FALSE     1   1      4      7 0.04176  8373.70    0 450.00 2.539   8
1.9    1  FALSE     1   1      4      7 0.04576 12318.20    0 600.00 2.628   9
```

There are 9 choices and x1~x4 are individual specific variables, and y1~y5 are alternative specific variables. x1 is categorical variable which takes 1 or 2. x2 and x3 are integer variable, x4 is categorical variable taking 7 integervalues. y are all numeric variables but y2 and y3 are censored so 0 is observed. 
So in the above example person1 chooses alternative 4 and x1~x4 are all same as they are individual specific.
I made a conditional multinomial logit formula like below.

And here's the problem. I think I made all the settings exactly same as in the mlogit package examples, but I keep getting this error message!

```
f <- mFormula(choice ~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5 | x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)

m <- mlogit(f, data = x, shape = "long", choice = "choice", alt.var = "alt", chid.var = "chid")

 Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 8.41187e-25
```

I'm fairly new here, and I really don't know if I am asking in the right fashion.
But I really need help, and I would appreciate if anyone can help me through this problem... Thank you!